# How to check for null widget value in dart ternary operator to display default image if null?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, null, conditional-operator

Hello I need some help with my flutter code
I'm loading my data from json and passing the data from one screen to another screen.
I want to use a ternary operator to check for null but keep getting errors.

I want to load a default image if there is no data, I'm getting error - **failed expression: a boolean expression must not be null.**

Below is a snippit of my code inside a stateful widget
widget.image contains the data for the image

```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  //load json data to each section, using index provided from list page.

  final herbName;
  final index;
  final image;
  final text;
  DetailScreen({this.herbName,this.index,this.image,this.text});

  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}
```

//the code below is located inside State

```
BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: **widget.image ? NetworkImage("http://images.neopets.com/altador/altadorcup/signup_full.gif")
                    :

                NetworkImage(widget.image),**

              )),
```

Comment: `image: NetworkImage(widget.image ?? "http://images....")`

Comment: Thanks, the ?? works ! What is the double question mark called again?

Comment: check https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these
1. `image: NetworkImage(widget.image ?? "http://images.neopets.com/altador/altadorcup/signup_full.gif")`

2. `image: widget.image == null ? NetworkImage("http://images.neopets.com/altador/altadorcup/signup_full.gif") : NetworkImage(widget.image);`

You are getting that error because widget.image is a String (and you didn't compare it to anything). The ternary operation works with Boolean